# exception thrown but not caught in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

hey i have been getting the same runtime error for a long time which is the exception im throwing is not being caught although i got a catch after its try and here is the code:

```
Company* Company::operator+=(Employee* emp){

if ((emp == NULL)) { //given a pointer to an element emp we check if the emp is NULL
    throw IllegalArguments();//we throw an error if it is null
}
if ((this->contains(emp->getID()) == false)) // we check if the Employee already exists in the Company
    _company.push_back(emp->clone());//a method to copy the found element
return this;
```

}

the IllegalArguments is a class i defined for throwing errors completely nothing special and here is its definition:

```
 #ifndef _ILLEGALARGUMENTS_
 #define _ILLEGALARGUMENTS_
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 class IllegalArguments {};
 #endif // !_ILLEGALARGUMENTS_
```

so all of my code compiles very well except for these lines of the main:

```
 try {
        *company += NULL;
     }
     catch (IllegalArguments exp) {
        cout << "IllegalArguments exception was thrown !!" << endl;
      }
```

so the project stops at the line of the catch and gives me this error message:

**Exception thrown at 0x74C0D722 in Projectinfinity.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: IllegalArguments at memory location 0x0096EA13.**

so the idea is that the company is a vector which contains in each index a pointer to an employee which is a class i defined and the operator += is to add an employee to the vector so i check if the pointer to add is null if it is null then i throw an error but apparently it looks like its not working with the catch thing although im throwing an exception by value and catching by value.

Comment: Have you got "break on exception" (not quite the right name as on tablet) set in the project properties?  It's conventional (but not required) to catch by const &.

Comment: By the way, your include guard is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).